# How can I recursively strip off exif info from all images in a directory?

Tags: command-line, batch, exiftool

```
for i in *.jpg; do echo "Processing $i"; exiftool -all= "$i"; done
```

I need to adapt this line of code which strips all exif info from images in a directory. I need it to;

- not fail if the current directory is empty
- be recursive to deal with sub-directories
- cover *.gif *.jpeg *.png as well

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you could modify it to use the `find` command rather than a for loop if your intent is to process all .jpg files.

Comment: it is, but I have no idea how  I'd do that?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509226/using-find-command-in-bash-script Vivek Sethi answer appears  to have the clues you seek.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/260810/how-can-i-read-and-remove-meta-exif-data-from-my-photos-using-the-command-line

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no need to script this, ExifTool can do it by itself and it will be much faster than looping through items.
`exiftool -r -all= -ext jpg -ext gif -ext png /path/to/top/directory/`

`-r` recurse through subdirectories
`-ext …` limit processed files to specified extentions, remove these items to process all files that Exiftool can remove metadata for.

Answer (score 1):

Since exiftool is awesome, then there's no need for it, but in principle you could do with `find` something like this...

First check that your search finds what you want (using -iname to make it search case insensitively since both `.JPG` and `.jpg` etc are common)

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -or -iname '*.png' -or -iname '*.jpeg' -or -iname '*.gif'
```

if will output a list of found files with paths starting here (including subdirectories)

then repeat adding the command to act on the files found at the end `| xargs exiftool -all=`

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -or -iname '*.png' -or -iname '*.jpeg' -or -iname '*.gif' | xargs exiftool -all=
```

or safer if filenames have spaces, to use null as a delimiter instead of spaces:

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -print0 -or -iname '*.png' -print0 -or -iname '*.jpeg' -print0 -or -iname '*.gif' -print0 | xargs --null exiftool -all=
```

If nothing matches (for example the directory is empty) then it does nothing

`.` is the current working directory. If you aren't there, replace `find .` with `find /path/to/parent/directory`